# Почему не растягивается QPieSeries и QChartView?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator, qlayout

Добавил круговую диаграмму внутрь фрейма в окне, но вместо нее вот такая шляпа размером 50х50 пикселей где-то.
[image: Картинка]

Код:

```
QPieSeries *series = new QPieSeries();
series->append("C++", 80);
series->append("C$", 70);
series->append("C$", 20);

QChart *chart = new QChart();
chart->addSeries(series);
chart->setTitle("Simple piechart example");
chart->legend()->hide();

QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
chartView->setParent(ui->frameQ);
```

Использование фрейма не обязательно, просто использовал как родителя. Но ничего не помогает. Подскажите, что не так. Сама форма - это QWidget, а не QMainWindow. Но мне нужно, чтобы диаграмма растянулась на все окно именно QWidget

Comment: Задайте вашему виджету лейаут widget->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout()), тогда все растянется

Comment: Увы, но даже Layout'ы не помогают. Не растягивается и все. Не знаю почему

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <QVBoxLayout>

int main(...) {
    QApplication a(...);

    QWidget* parent = new QWidget();
    parent->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());
    //...

    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);    
    parent->layout()->addWidget(chartView);
    parent->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```